# Is aspect-oriented modelling possible in papyrus?

Tags: uml, papyrus

I am new in papyrus modelling. I asked the same question in Papyrus forum, but I didn't get any reply. I believe, somebody could help me in this regard. Anyway, I am wondering how to do aspect-oriented modelling in papyrus state machine. I have some state machine. where each state has it's own state invariant. Apart from this, there is a number of constraints that act as state invariant in multiple states. So, adding all of those constraints as state invariant in each of those states would make the state machine more complex and messy. Probably, aspect-oriented modelling is a better option in this scenario. So, a single constraint can be added to the state invariant of states of the same aspect. i.e., the complete state invariant of a state would be its own state invariant and the constraint from the aspect. 
Is this possible in papyrus? Any idea how to do this? Any suggestion?